# Pip error when trying to install zlib

Tags: python, pip, zlib

I'm new to Python and programming and am having trouble installing `zlib` through `pip`, I keep having the issue below:

```
pip install zlib
Collecting zlib
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for zlib
```

Comment: The `zlib` package comes with Python. Why are you trying to install it? It doesn't exist under that name in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Answer (score 3):

`zlib` is not a python package, you can try `yum/apt-get install zlib-devel` or `yum/apt-get install zlib`.

Answer (score 1):

On mac using homebrew:

```
brew install zlib
```