# Trying to build a Docker Image, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

Tags: docker

I am running a script to create a Docker Image

```
# 4. docker build -t my-layer .
# 5. docker run --name my-container my-layer
# 6. docker cp my-container:/opt/python-3.9.6/aws-layer/my-layer.zip .
# Your Layer is ready.

FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel gzip make -y
RUN yum install wget tar zip -y
WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tgz
RUN tar xzf Python-3.9.6.tgz
COPY requirements.txt /opt/Python-3.9.6/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/Python-3.9.6
RUN ./configure --enable-optimizations
RUN make altinstall
RUN rm -f /opt/Python-3.9.6.tgz
RUN mkdir -p aws-layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
RUN pip3.9 install -r requirements.txt -t aws-layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
RUN cd aws-layer && zip -r9 my-layer.zip .
```

and I get this error message;

> #14 156.6 Traceback (most recent call last):
> #14 156.6   File "", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
> #14 156.6 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
> #14 156.6
> #14 156.6 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> #14 156.6
> #14 156.6 Traceback (most recent call last):
> #14 156.6   File "", line 568, in _get_data
> #14 156.6   File "", line 523, in _get_decompress_func
> #14 156.6 zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

I try running pip install zlib but this command does not work, it does not find zlib.
I am using windows and I cannot run sudo apt ... commands.
So how do I fix this?

EDIT
The problem was fixed thanks to a comment by @Paolo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error when trying to install zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403874/pip-error-when-trying-to-install-zlib)

Comment: The problem is that I am using windows, so sudo yum or sudo apt does not work

Comment: What do you mean? You are running this in a amazonlinux docker container. Your host OS doesn't matter

Comment: @Paolo - apologies for my previous answer, I have now figured out what you meant. Inserting the line "RUN yum install zlib-devel -y" in the beginning of the script fixed the problem. Thank you for that, the problem is now solved.